# Errors from NIntegrate when integrating Green's function

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I have the code used to calculate density of states using integral of the Green's function.  Unfortunately, the code does not work.   I am supposed to get a plot of a gausian like curve with a dimple in the middle:

```
integral[j_, s_, nn_, oo_] :=
  Module[{},
    ListPlot[
      Table[
        {e, -1/Pi*
          Im[NIntegrate[1/(e + I*s - 2*j*cos[kl]), {kl, -Pi, Pi}]]}, {e, -20, 20, nn}], 
       Joined -> True, 
       AxesLabel -> {"E", "DOS"},
       PlotRange -> oo]] 

integral[1, 1, 30, 30]
```

I am getting the following error messages:

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 1/((-20.+0.02 I)-2 cos[kl]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-3.14159,3.14159}}. >>
>   NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 1/((20. +0.02 I)-2 cos[kl]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-3.14159,3.14159}}. >>
>   NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 1/((0. +0.02 I)+e-2 cos[kl]) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-3.14159,3.14159}}. >>
>   General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumr will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>   Flatten::normal:

Any suggestions?

Comment: All built-in functions start with a capital letter. Change `cos` to `Cos`

Comment: `j` should probably be `I`, and try PlotRange->All.

Answer (score 1):

```
myintegral[j_, s_, nn_, oo_List] := 
 Module[{}, 
  ListPlot[Table[{e, -π Im[NIntegrate[
        1/(e + I s - 2 I Cos[kl]), {kl, -π, π}]]}, 
       {e, -20, 20, nn}], 
  Joined -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {"E", "DOS"}, 
  PlotRange -> oo]] 

myintegral[2, 4, 1, {0, 4}]
```

works fine.  Note that PlotRange takes a `List` {ymin, ymax}.